# Powershell use twice invoke-command

Tags: powershell

is possible how set varraible in local and move it to twice invoke

ForExample

```
$id = 12356
$Test = invoke-command -servername Server1 -scriptblock { invoke-command -servername server2 -scriptblcok {get-process -id $id}}
```

When i used $using:id I get this varriable in one jump invoke-command but second jump i lost this varriable.
Thx

Comment: For starters, you will face a [double-hop issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.2) with your current code.

Comment: `Invoke-Command { Invoke-Command { $id = $args[0];... } -ArgumentList $using:id}` (although, as @SantiagoSquarzon points out, this will fail due to no forwardable credentials available at the second hop)